# Android CMake use prebuild .a library

Tags: android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I am totally new to CMake and using NDK in common. I figured out to write my JNI interface and use 2 methods which are part of a C library. I compiled this library as a static library and got the .a file. Now I'm a little bit lost as I don't understand how to tell Android Studio to use this library when trying to find the called functions.

This is my current CMakeLists.txt which is located in the "app" module folder.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(my-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/my-lib.cpp )

target_link_libraries(my-lib z crypto)

target_link_libraries(my-lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/libmine.a)
```

On compilation I get the warning that no reference can be found to the called functions. Is my CMakeLists.txt correct and how do I include the .h file for the functions? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What tool chain did you use to build your static library?  You need to use the Android tool chain to compile all the code as you are cross-compiling.

Comment: I compiled it using gcc on an Ubuntu VM. How can I compile it using CMake directly?

Comment: It's documented here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain  Remember that building for Android is usually cross-compiling for various flavours of ARM chip (and others).

Comment: Thank you I will have a look there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how to tell Android Studio to use this library when trying to find the called functions

In order to use your native libs, i.e. `libmy-lib.so` for your case, you need to load this shared lib inside your java part like below.

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("my-lib");
    }
```

> Is my CMakeLists.txt correct ?

Yes, it is correct, but not really perfect.

> and how do I include the .h file for the functions

In order to make yourself work easier to add the header file includes, you need to configure `CMakelists.txt` a little bit. E.g. You may have a directory structure as below, if you only have the `app/src/main/cpp`, then can just remove those unrelated dirs and configurations.

```
    app
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── src
        ├── foo
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── foo.cpp
        │   └── foo.h
        ├── main
        │   └── cpp
        │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │       └── my-lib.cpp
        └── test
            ├── CMakeLists.txt
            └── google_test_classXXX.cpp
```

Then you need to configure your `app/CMakelists.txt` as below.

```
    # set the root directory as ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} which is a
    # CMAKE build-in function to return the current dir where your CMakeLists.txt is. 
    # Specifically, it is "<your-path>/App/"
    set(APP_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

    # set your 3 other root dirs, i.e. foo, main and test under app/src.
    set(APP_ROOT_SRC_DIR ${APP_ROOT_DIR}/src)
    set(APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR ${APP_ROOT_SRC_DIR}/foo)
    set(APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR ${APP_ROOT_SRC_DIR}/main)
    set(APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR ${APP_ROOT_SRC_DIR}/test)

    # set your include paths into "SHARED_INCLUDES" variable so that you can quote your header file without adding its relative paths. 
    set(SHARED_INCLUDES
                    ${APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR}
                    # ${APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>

                    ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}
                    ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}/cpp
                    # ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>

                    ${APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR}
                    # ${APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>
                    )

    # This function will have effect to all the downstream cmakelist files. 
    include_directories(${SHARED_INCLUDES})

    add_library(my-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/my-lib.cpp )

    target_link_libraries(my-lib z crypto)

    target_link_libraries(my-lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/libmine.a)

    # remember to include downstream cmakelist files for foo, main and test.
    add_subdirectory(${APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR} bin-dir)
    add_subdirectory(${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR} bin-dir)
    add_subdirectory(${APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR} bin-dir)
```

**----Edited----**

For how to link the prebuild .a libs.

```
    # Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
    # can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
    # build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.
    target_link_libraries(my-lib -Wl,--whole-archive ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/libmine.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

**---- Edited to answer your three questions ----**

> What is part of the CMakeLists.txt inside of the cpp directoy?
>   Does it need to be in the cpp directory or in the main directory?

Theoretically, you can just have one `CMakelists.txt` for all your source code dirs and header dirs, but once your project evolves to a very large scale, this all-in-one `CMakelists.txt` will become quite complicate and not readable and maintainable. Usually, each cmake module should have its own `CMakeLists.txt` file so that it is modularised and easier to manage. E.g. `cpp` dir has one `CMakeLists.txt` to manage all its sub dirs if any, so do `main` and `test` "module".

> And how do I include a .h file of my .a lib - #include  does not work.

As I mentioned above, you need to configure `SHARED_INCLUDES` to add your relative paths to the headers (`.h`) of your `.a`, so that you can simply use `#include <xxx.h>` for header inclusion.

```
    set(SHARED_INCLUDES
                ${APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR}
                # ${APP_ROOT_FOO_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>

                ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}
                ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}/cpp
                # ${APP_ROOT_MAIN_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>

                ${APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR}
                # ${APP_ROOT_TEST_DIR}/<your-other-child-dirs>
       )
```

**Set your include paths into "SHARED_INCLUDES" variable so that you can quote your header file without adding its relative paths.**

---

**Edit to answer your question about how to configure architectures**

you can configure your targets inside `build.gradle` as below:

```
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                ...
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The CMake build process will take each ABI one by one. The variable `${ANDROID_ABI}` inside `CMakelists.txt` can tell you the current ABI (architecture) it is building. And you can also use this variable to configure your library PATHs if you need.

E.g. This variable `${ANDROID_ABI}` inside

```
target_link_libraries(${SHARED_LIBRARY_NAME} -Wl,--whole-archive ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmine.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
```

will be replaced with `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86` or  `x86_64` during the build time.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Three questions: What is part of the CMakeLists.txt inside of the cpp directoy? Does it need to be in the cpp directory or in the main directory? And how do I include a .h file of my .a lib - #include <xxx.h> does not work.

Comment: So that means I have to keep the header files inside the app, right? I think I missunderstood this and didn't add them before

Comment: You can put your header files wherever you like, but remember to add the directory path into your include_directories so that you don’t have to add its relative path

Comment: Okay thank you, that helped. One more question: Is there a way in CMake to tell the target_link_libraries which architecture we are on? I included arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86 and x86_64 but is there a variable so CMake knows which one it should take?

Comment: Thanks again so much for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to specify the include directories as well using 
[include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) command.
Second it seems you want to link a *static* library(.a) with your final *shared* library. This cannot be done. You either need shared libraries throughout or static libraries throughout.