# add include path for C/C++ in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to android studio and familiar with eclipse, so I wanna develop a native C++ project, I created the project and set the native environment and compiled the projects successfully, now I wanna use a shared library which is `assimp`, I created a `jniLibs` folder under `src/main` but i can't include any file from that library, in Eclipse there is a setting for include path.

Comment: take a look at my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188683/android-cmake-use-prebuild-a-library/51202467#51202467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android native development, you can use cmake tool chains. Inside your `CMakeLists.txt`, you need to add the include path if you want to include any header files inside.

E.g.

```
include_directories(src/main/c)
```